# Сделать текст жирным в сообщении от бота node-telegram-bot-api

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

Как сделать текст жирным в сообщении от бота в telegram

```
import TelegramBot from 'node-telegram-bot-api';

const bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });

console.log("Started");

bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;
    const text = msg.text.toLowerCase();

    if (text == '123') {
        await bot.sendMessage(chatId, '*bold*');
    }
})
```

Comment: `{ parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2' }` https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node-telegram-bot-api/index.d.ts#L168

Answer (score 0):

await bot.sendMessage(chatId, '**bold**', {
parse_mode: 'HTML'
});